# Get the latest version of all files in a folder at certain date VSS Sourcesafe

Tags: date, visual-sourcesafe, versions

What I'm trying to do is get the picture of how all the files were in their latest version at a certain date.

I already tried - right click on the folder> show history and input two dates/versions  but what I get is all the files that have been changed in the indicated interval of time.

I'm using Microsof Visual Sourcesafe 2005.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already tried - right click on the folder> show history and input
>   two dates/versions but what I get is all the files that have been
>   changed in the indicated interval of time.

After that, choose one file and click button Get, you will get a dialog asking "Get the entire project containing this file version?", choose yes.